# How to create a static library in osx

Tags: objective-c, c, macos, cocoa, lpsolve

lpsolve is a C library that can be used to solve linear programming problems. They have some header files and using that you can create a dylib or a static library(.a). The [osx library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/lpsolve/files/lpsolve/5.5.2.0/) has some header files, a dylib file and .a file. but these were compiled for 32 bit. But OSX is using 64 bit OS now and I have to recompile these so that I can use their api.

Could anyone give me any links about how to compile these .h files for 64 bit os?

Comment: You can't compile header files, you'll need to download the source.

Comment: I have the source header files. How do use these .h files to compile the library.

Comment: You have the source or you have the headers. "Source headers" doesn't make any sense. Do you have .c files?

Comment: I only have .h files. There are no .c files

Comment: Fortunately for you, it looks like you can [download the source](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/lpsolve/lpsolve/5.5.2.0/lp_solve_5.5.2.0_source.tar.gz?r=http%3A%2F%2Fsourceforge.net%2Fprojects%2Flpsolve%2Ffiles%2Flpsolve%2F5.5.2.0%2F&ts=1395798242&use_mirror=tcpdiag).

Comment: @kevin, Thanks for giving the link to the source. The folder contains files like this http://imgur.com/K7dkZIr . Now I have to use these to create a dylib or .so file?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you rock [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) (and if you're not, go and install it, like, right now),

```
$ brew install lp_solve
```

and you're done. In case you prefer [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/), I believe you can do

```
$ port install lp_solve
```

Comment: 404 not found. I am using homebrew.

Comment: Works for me. Are you sure your network works okay? Alternately, `brew update` might help.

Comment: yes. xyz@yaw:~$  brew install lp_solve
Error: No available formula for lp_solve
Searching taps...
Error: 404 Not Found
Please report this bug:
    https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/wiki/troubleshooting

Comment: Ah, I see what might be going on - it's in a different repo. Can you try `brew tap homebrew/science`, then try installing again?